# Testing another wifi password while in access point

Tags: wifi, password, wifi-hotspot

(Please apologize my english)

My wifi interface can't be connected to two networks at the same time (error "this device is busy" when I tried with virtual interface).

I created an access-point with a captive portal so when the users connect to the access-point they get my website, which display all the detected wifi around my computed (despit I do this for a specific hardware, I want first make it run on my computer).
For scanning the availables wifi while the interface is in access-point mode, I need to run `sudo iw dev <interface> scan ap-force`.
The `ap-force` parameter make me able to do this while in access-point mode (if there is a way to do this with `nmcli` instead of `iw` it would be perfect as I managed the rest of my code to only use `nmcli`).

Now that the user can connect to the access-point, get the list of the availables wifi, choose one of them and specify password if needed, I want to check if the password is correct, without stopping the access-point, to be able to notify the user if the password is correct or not.

All of that have for purpose to make the user able to connect the hardware to the network without physical intervention (no keyboard, no screen, no console for the client ;-) ).

Thank you in advance for your answers !
If I did a misteak in this post, let me know :-)

Comment: What if your access point and the other wifi network you wish to probe are not on the same channel?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question...

Even if they are not on the same channel, the interface see them when using `sudo iw <interface> scan ap-force`, but I didn't find yet a way to check the password without previously stopping AP-mode...

Comment: I'm not an expert on wifi and radios but my question was leading to the assumption that you can't talk on one channel using the same radio that is actively serving clients on a different channel.

Comment: I'm not an expert too, and the possibility to scan available wifis during ap-mode open perspectives for me... Maybe ?